# Error using shred

Tags: mount, error-handling

I have an 8GB SSD that had Windows 8.1. I was using a text editor and it locked up on me. I tried to format add a new partition and nothing happen. So I'm using Ubuntu on a external SD. I can read the drive in the BIOS and in the OS, but I can't delete or do anything to it. I checked online on how to erase and clear the 8GB SSD by using the command shred. I did and I got this error message: `fdatasync failed input and output error`. How can I wipe the SSD and reformat it? I know it can be done, because I have done it with another machine that had Windows 8.1 but was using SATA and diskpart. When I try to mount it I get this error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/bigby/6A9CA8A19CA868F1:  
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o 
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177"  
"/dev/sda1" "/media/bigby/6A9CA8A19CA868F1"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: 
Corrupted file $UpCase  
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1':Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Comment: Looks like the disk is failing.  You might take a look at the SMART status in the disk utility.

Comment: I have done everything. The status says ok. But i cant seem to format anyone knows how to wipe it clean.

Comment: OK does not mean OK... how many pending or uncorrectable sectors are there?  Often drives will have quite a few and still say the overall status is OK.  Also you might check `dmesg` for more detailed errors.  I suppose it could be a bad sata cable or something.

Comment: Its not sata, its pata drive from a dell mini 910. And all test came back ok. I tried benchmark tests and all no damage.

Comment: @DigiTal: Take the drive out of the PC, hook it up to the second machine you have and then let us know what the drive name is there as I'll give you a command starting with `dd` (a.k.a. **D**isk **D**estroyer) but before I give you the rest of the command, I need to be *absolutely sure* it works on your second machine!

Comment: Then check `dmesg` for the cause of the error.

Comment: @fabby i don't have a machine that has on board pata. Only my mini dell does. So i just bought a pata external adapter that is pata to usb 3.0. That will come tomorrow hopefully. @ how can i use that command?.

Comment: We need to know the exact sdX (where X is a letter from A-Z on the other machine) and then I can finally answer your question and then you can accept it.

Comment: Sda and it has sda1.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the drive letter is sda on the other machine (sdb is more likely). Double check before wipe!!!!!

Comment: Sda1 is the drive, when i go to disk manager it shows.

Comment: @Elder Geek that command will wipe out my drive complete. Would I be able to reformat ssd and start all over?.

Comment: Yes. "How can i wipe the ssd and reformat it" I'll add formatting to my answer

Comment: How can i upload a picture on here so i can show you.

Comment: you can upload to imgur.com and provide a link. Once your reputation is high enough you will be able to add them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As Fabby indicates this can be done with dd however it can be a time consuming process and as dd doesn't provide status during the wipe I prefer to use dc3dd for these tasks. The command to wipe a drive with dc3dd is `sudo dc3dd wipe=/dev/sdX` where X is the drive you wish to wipe (a in your comment, c in my case). dc3dd will provide output regarding the process as it's running. Here's an example:

[image]

If you don't have dc3dd installed on your system you can install it with `sudo apt-get install dc3dd`

You can partition and format your drive a number of ways from the CLI using fdisk and mkfs or using the GUI with gparted or the Ubuntu installer can do it for you. Specific instructions for these approaches are readily available. There is a full manual for gparted [here.](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual) Comment if more help is needed.

While the above solution works fine on a functioning drive, based on your comments your drive is not functioning properly and should be replaced or repaired by the manufacturer (if under warranty) or by you (if not).

Comment: I tried that, seems it doesn't work. it deletes the partition but when I refresh it...it comes back.

Comment: You have to reboot after changing a partition table for it to refresh.....

Comment: Do you have teamviewer

Comment: No, I don't use teamviewer. Did you use dc3dd on the correct drive? If you did it should have no partition table.

Comment: I used it and it didnt correct it. I proble doing something wrong here.

Comment: dc3dd wipes the drive entirely including the partition table and all data. After that completes you can create a new partition table and file system with gparted. What error message do you get and at what stage of the process??

Comment: Ok its showing copy like on the image you showed. After it goes 100% what is the next thing

Comment: Create a new partition table and file system with gparted. See the link to the manual in my answer. If it's still not clear leave me a comment with what is confusing you.

Comment: Nope it doesn't help...

Comment: Alright ive done what you said i did the dc3dd  command 100%  but the format still there. So when i did the gparted and delete the partition and reformat and add a new partition..the old one comes back.

Comment: Are you certain you wiped the correct drive? if sync is failing we are back to psusi diagnosis. Drive is failing. Replace it.

Comment: /dev/sda which is the one that is currpeted. I am running the os on my ext usb drive.

Comment: Here is the image http://sociaconnect.com/linux/error.jpg

Comment: Well that seems clear. I'll add the image to your question.

Comment: @DigiTal IF you did a full wipe with `dc3dd` as you say and you are still getting the error in the image you provided. The drive is shot. (specifically, the write circuitry failed to write zeros over the partition table and the rest of the drive). I stand by my answer. You must contact the manufacturer. There's a slim chance that you require a firmware update but it's far more likely the drive is done.

Comment: But when i look at the disk drive  in gparted it shows ntfs is still there and cant be mounted or formated or anything..

Comment: Yea the drive could be shot. Ill just replace it.

Comment: @ElderGeek: I use ddrescue instead of dd.  how does dc3dd stack up?  (Chat??? AksUbuntu General Room?)

Comment: I fixed my problem, now my 8gb ssd works perfect. I found out that it was runing on two firmwares not one. So a new friend gave me this app that works and i got it as a backup.

Comment: I'm glad you got it resolved although your solution is baffling at best....

Comment: Well, i knew it wasnt dead, thanks for the help EG. I want to learn how to use wine. I got some programs that arent install but runable.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine

Comment: I saw that, but didnt find out how to move a whole folder into wine.

Comment: I doubt that is the correct approach. Search the site for answers on what you are trying to do and if you don't find the answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: I found it, I had to type browse to find c:/ folder